# How to get accessToken(response coming from the server)

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hello stuck on 'Retrofit2' thing. Can somebody please help me how could I possibly get the accessToken. This 'accessToken' will only be created from the server if the user logged in.
[image]

Comment: call retrofit, build retrofit with header & body and base url, create request and response model for send and fetch data. for more about retrofit. read [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
 
       Make Object from JSON. You may use jsonToPojo android studio plugin.

Step 2:
Process result from onResponse:

```
ApiCall apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiCall.class);
        Call<Api> callForLogin = apiService.getLoginResult("user_name","Password");
        callForDrawList.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResultObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResultObject> call, Response<LoginResultObject> response) {
                String accessToken=response.body().getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DrawResultsApi> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

I think it may help you...
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no such this as `getAccessToken()` in the response body. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. Let me try it first if this one works.

Comment: Wow...Great...Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to use retrofit. Something you need is just a simple request like below:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthenticationResponse>() {             @Override             public void onResponse(Call<AuthenticationResponse> call, Response<AuthenticationResponse> response) {                    if (response.code() == 200)                     mAuthenticateView.showPhoneNumberSentSuccessfully(response.body().getToken(), response.body().getExpiresIn());                 else                     mAuthenticateView.showMessage(response.message());             }             @Override             public void onFailure(Call<AuthenticationResponse> call, Throwable t) {     }         });
```

For more information see this tutorial:
[Using Retrofit 2.x as REST client](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

Comment: I know a bit. Thanks. gotta get back if this works... Still reading the link you gave.